How to execute a playwright component test without the playwright test runner?
I'm interested in trying Component Testing with playwright.
Because of my setup, I cannot use the playwright test runner, so I'd like to produce a Node executable that I can just run.
For regular (non component) tests, this can be done like this but component tests have this mount parameter that I don't know how to produce without the runner.
test('event should work', async ({ mount }) => {
  let clicked = false;

  // Mount a component. Returns locator pointing to the component.
  const component = await mount(
    <Button title="Submit" onClick={() => { clicked = true }}></Button>
  );

  // As with any Playwright test, assert locator text.
  await expect(component).toContainText('Submit');

  // Perform locator click. This will trigger the event.
  await component.click();

  // Assert that respective events have been fired.
  expect(clicked).toBeTruthy();
});


Can you explain "because of my setup I cannot use the test runner"? In a Node script you can just import test from playwright/test. What stops you using it?

Did you try with other runners?

Looking at the sources of playwright-ct-core (v1.49.1), it seems like the component testing feature builds up on @playwright/test and is strongly tied to Playwright's test execution model. The core function mount is provided as a fixture only. So, executing Playwright component tests with another test runner (or none at all) does not seem feasible, currently.
